# How to show each character 1 by one and display it as a label

Tags: c#, winforms, char

I have tried to convert the char to ToString() but it only shows the last character of the sentence which is "N" from the admin. Basically i want to show the whole sentence by show each of the characters with the thread.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        string quote;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

           quote = "Tips: Sometimes just leave her, to pause. - Admin";
            for (int i=0; i < quote.Length; i++){

               label1.Text =quote[i].ToString();
                Thread.Sleep(100);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This it the output:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AmPqo.png)
I did increase the length of the label too:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aBLjT.png)
This is what I really want guys:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0bE1u.png)

Comment: Try label1.Text +=quote[i].ToString();

Comment: It shows the whole text but its not showing each character 1 by one.. btw thanks for the reply

Comment: You should use a [`Timer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.timer?view=windowsdesktop-7.0) that refreshes the UI Thread every 100ms

Comment: @TimSchmelter u can use timer for threads? How can I do that can you show me

Comment: @Avinash: look at the link in the comment, you see an example.

Comment: @TimSchmelter woah things got complicated so fast haha

Comment: @TimSchmelter i dont know how to apply it but i have tried timer for animations before

Comment: @TimSchmelter all i have to do is put the timer and start it off ??

Comment: @MickyD i thought it will display each character of the string with a delay

Comment: Sleep will block the U thread so that it cannot redraw the display.

Comment: Use a `Timer` instead, specifically a `System.Windows.Forms.Timer`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commented you should use a winforms [`Timer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.timer?view=windowsdesktop-7.0) to update the UI-thread every 100 ms:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Windows.Forms.Timer updateLabelTimer = new();
    string quote = "Tips: Sometimes just leave her, to pause. - Admin";        
    int currentIndex = 0;

    updateLabelTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(UpdateLabelHandler);
    updateLabelTimer.Interval = 100;
    updateLabelTimer.Start();

    void UpdateLabelHandler(object? timerSender, EventArgs args)
    {
        label1.Text += quote[currentIndex];
        if (++currentIndex == quote.Length)
        {
            updateLabelTimer.Enabled = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It freaking worked man thanks a lot!!

Comment: By this way you're not using threads right?

Comment: @Avinash. they are hidden but a timer is a separate thread